# Alternate way to read a file as json using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a file that contains information similar to the example shown below. I would like to know if there is a way to read this file using python and use it as json. I am aware of how to open it and process the text but is there another way?

Example:

```
key={{name='foo', etc..},{},{},{}}
```

Comment: What you have there is neither valid Python nor JSON syntax.

Comment: I'm aware that the syntax is not valid JSON or python. I'm trying to find a way using the Python to convert the date to JSON or a Dictionary. Either one will suffice.

Comment: I would prefer not to use ast if that is at all possible. If someone has ever encountered this and has a solution I would appreciate a response. thanks

Comment: We can use regular expression to change **name='foo'** to **"name":"foo"**, the problem is **key** looks like a list, yet it uses curly braces. It is hard for the code to determine if that is a list or a dictionary.

Comment: Where did you get that text? Perhaps we can start there to investigate which language produces it. It does not look like any language that I know (but then I only know 1 or 2 languages)

Comment: For anyone with the need to parse lua data structures in python I found this little gem. https://github.com/SirAnthony/slpp.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your content to be treated as json you need to have a valid json syntax:

```
{"key":[{"name": "foo"},{},{},{}]}
```

Then you can use json library to convert it to a dictionary:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"key":[{"name": "foo"},{},{},{}]}')
{u'key': [{u'name': u'foo'}, {}, {}, {}]}
```

Additionally, if your file content cannot be changed to a correct json syntax, then you will need to develop a parser for your specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will begin work on a parser as conversion to JSON  is not an option unless I want to copy file locally and perform text manipulation. I will have to experiment to see which one is less time intensive.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a few different languages I was able to determine that the data struct was a Lua container. I found a simple lua-python parser currently available here github.com/SirAnthony/slpp and I was able to parse(decode) the lua data structure. Below is an example of parsing a lua container with slpp.py I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.

```
>>> from slpp import slpp as lua
>>> data = lua.decode('{ array = { 65, 23, 5 }, dict = { string = "value",    array = { 3, 6, 4}, mixed = { 43, 54.3, false, string = "value", 9 } } }')
>>> print data
```

{'array': [65, 23, 5], 'dict': {'mixed': {0: 43, 1: 54.33, 2: False, 4: 9, 'string': 'value'}, 'array': [3, 6, 4], 'string': 'value'}}